# Retrieve data by user input with a message (PL/SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

[image]

I want to how to retrieve data from the table I have added here by inserting C_Id as the user input with defined variables and exceptions. If any customer is not available it has to display a message showing "No customer found". Please help me to understand this one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If it is a stored procedure (should be; it accepts a parameter) and you just want to *display* what you found, then this might be one option:

```
create or replace procedure p_test (par_c_id in customer_details.c_id%type)
is
  l_row customer_details%rowtype;
begin
  select *
    into l_row
    from customer_details
    where c_id = par_c_id;
    
  dbms_output.put_line(l_row.customer_name ||', '||
                          l_row.address       ||', '||
                          to_char(l_row.date_of_joined, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
                         );
exception
  when no_data_found then
    dbms_output.put_line('No customer found');
end;
/
```

Then run it as

```
set serveroutput on
begin
  p_test(121);
end;
/
```

What does it do?

- accepts a parameter
- declares local variable which is equal to table's *rowtype*
- select everything into the variable
- using `dbms_output.put_line`, display elements you want
- if nothing has been found, exception (`no_data_found`) is raised and handled in a way that you display appropriate message

Note that such an option works if tool you use (e.g. SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, TOAD, ...) allow displaying result of `dbms_output.put_line`. Otherwise, if you use e.g. Oracle Apex, procedure will still work, but you won't see anything.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how to add user inputs?

Comment: It is a parameter you pass to the procedure. How will you pass it? Depends on a tool. In SQL*Plus, you'd use a substitution variable, e.g. `p_test(&par_id);`. Or, in TOAD you could use a bind variable, e.g. `p_test(:par_id);`

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur support